# Ping, nslookup and remote desktop issues

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, ping

I have two computers named HOST and HOST2. We are migrating the server from HOST to HOST2. HOST is a old system running windows server 2003 and has static ip configured. HOST2 is the new system running windows server 2008 and has DHCP enabled. Both of them have internet connection and I can access the web. The workgroup is setup as WORKGROUP for both the machines.

I can access HOST from HOST2 through remote desktop. But I cannot access HOST2 from HOST, though remote desktop is enabled on HOST2. I can **ping** HOST2 from HOST1 and viceversa. But **nslookup** fails on both the machines. On HOST1 it says the record is not present on DNS server. On HOST2 the DNS server times out after 2 seconds. But if I do **nslookup** on HOST with the ipaddress of HOST2, it returns the DHCP server record. **nslookup** on HOST2 says DNS server timed out fo all the machines I ping (ex: google.com, cricinfo.com  etc)

HOST2 is a new system and I just plugged the interned chord from another old machine to this machine. Do I need to manually register the new machine with the DNS ? Doesn't DHCP take care of this? I wish to remote desktop HOST2 from HOST.

The windows 2008 box requires network level authentication which the 2003 box doesn't support. What has this to do with the nslookup failure on HOST2? The **ipconfig /all** for HOST2 shows three DNS servers, two of which are also shown on HOST1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you even running a local DNS server?  You mention your computers are just in a workgroup and not in a domain.  If you are running a local DNS server does it accept Dynamic DNS updates?  Have you logged into the DNS server and checked to see if the records where created?

On your windows 2008 box how have you configured the Remote Desktop to allow connections from any version of remote desktop?  Have you made sure a firewall exception was created in the windows firewall?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see that the windows 2008 box requires network level authentication which the 2003 box doesn't support.